# Tutorial on isPointinPath not copying to my computer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found this helpful tutorial 
http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/february/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-ispointinpath-function.html

i copied it into my own text editor and nothing happens when I open it. I changed it by adding a declaration

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>exampleMouseOver</title>
  </head>
<script>
    window.onload = function (e)
    {
        var canvas  = document.getElementById('cvs');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Draw the rectangle
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(50,50,100,100);
        context.fill();

        context.fillStyle = 'red';

        // Draw the circle
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(450,175, 50, 0,2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fill();

        context.fillStyle = 'green';

        // Draw the shape
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(250,100);
        context.lineTo(350,175);
        context.lineTo(325,215);
        context.lineTo(185,195);
        context.fill();



        canvas.onmousemove = function (e)
        {
            var canvas = e.target;
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            // This gets the mouse coordinates (relative to the canvas)
            var mouseXY = RGraph.getMouseXY(e);
            var mouseX  = mouseXY[0];
            var mouseY  = mouseXY[1];


            // Replay the rectangle path (no need to fill() it) and test it
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(50,50,100,100);

            if (context.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                return;
            }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            // Replay the circle path (no need to fill() it) and test it
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(450,175, 50, 0,2 * Math.PI, false);

            if (context.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                return;
            }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            // Replay the irregular shape path (no need to fill() it) and test it
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(250,100);
            context.lineTo(350,175);
            context.lineTo(325,215);
            context.lineTo(185,195);

            if (context.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                return;
            }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            // Return the cursor to the default style
            canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a body element and a canvas element.  Also your script element needs to be inside either your head element or your body element.

The following is what the sample was using, but did not include in their sample code:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="cvs" width="600" height="250" style="border: 1px solid gray; cursor: pointer;">[No canvas support]</canvas>
</body>
```

**Edit**: Additionally the code is calling "RGraph.getMouseXY(e)", which is in a library file that you are not referencing.  You can either add a reference to that library or get the mouse position yourself.

If you want to use other parts of the RGraph library, for drawing charts, you should add the library.  To add the library you should follow the instructions on the RGraph site related to downloading and starting with RGraph (http://www.rgraph.net/docs/starting-with-rgraph.html).

If this was just a sample that happened to do what you wanted to do, you should get the mouse position yourself.  You can do this by changing these lines:

```
var mouseXY = RGraph.getMouseXY(e);
var mouseX  = mouseXY[0];
var mouseY  = mouseXY[1];
```

to these:

```
var mouseX  =  e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var mouseY  =  e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

This may not be the most robust solution, but it should suffice for your purposes.  Essentially you are getting the mouse position in the window, then subtracting the top-left of the canvas in the window, so that you are left with the mouse position in the canvas.

Comment: ok great! I did that and it actually shows up now. However I get the desired outcome on the whole canvas rather than the particular shapes

Comment: I was able to reproduce and fix your issue on Chrome, see my edit for details.